# Renaming files based on the contents of a text file

Tags: files, rename

I have lots of point files I need to change for model input. I want to rename lots of these files based on the contents of a file. These files are text files arranged in rows.

file name: `data_lat_long.txt`

```
1 data_20_20
2 data_30_40
3 data_50_60
.
.
```

and so on

my files are named `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, etc,.

I want `1` to be changed in to `data_20_20`, `2` in to `data_30_40` and so on.

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L, please remember to mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted (the tick mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 8):

```
while read line ; do 
    mv $line 
done < data_lat_long.txt
```

Redirect the contents of `data_lat_long.txt` to a `while` loop that uses `read` to read in the each line of the file and for each line assign it to a variable called `$line`. Then run `mv` with the contents of `$line` as an argument (which is the from and to parts you have specified in your `data_lat_long.txt` file). Keep on looping until the end of file.

Note this implicitly expects that neither file names in your `data_lat_long.txt` contain spaces (so that there are only two columns).

If files have spaces in them, then I suggest a comma separator in your file:

```
1,space file1
2,space file2
3,space file3
```

and then use:

```
while IFS=',' read -a files 
do 
   mv "${files[0]}" "${files[1]}" 
done < list.txt
```

That makes use of the `-a` option of `read` which assigns the text separated by the `IFS` (in this case comma) to an array called `$files`. We then index the various elements on the `mv` and quote the arguments with double quotes `""`. This is so the array value is expanded on execution of the `mv` command *and* so the space in the file is not seen as  argument separator by `mv`. `mv 1 space file1` does not do the same thing as `mv "1" "space file1"`. The former command attempts to move files/directories called `1` and `space` to a directory called `file1`.

Comment: thank you very much!! you are awesome. You solved my problems and saved me from wasting lots of time on that.

Comment: No problem! Like the other question if you can mark it as the accepted answer that would be appreciated!

Comment: If you could mark it as so that would be great, details at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers